Searching for a sci-fi mech anime from the early 2000s
Okay, so I'm searching for a specific anime that had an aspect of mecha in it. Needle in a haystack, I know, but I'm beseeching the greater knowledge center of the Internet for this.
So all I can really remember about it is that it had 2 people taking turns piloting one mecha in separate cockpits, and to change they said "You have control"/"I have control". And I'm like 90% sure it aired on the sci-fi channel at some point probably between 1998-2005 but I couldn't find anything that sounded familiar on the list.
I think the mech was short and wide because the 2 pilots were facing opposite directions and the cockpits rotated when they switched controls. and the only part about it I remember was them under water I believe.

Maybe Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann?
The two central characters' mechs (Gurren and Lagann) combine to form the eponymous Gurren Lagann.
They stay in their respective cockpits post-combining, but they both retain control of sorts.
According to Wikipedia, it aired on the Sci-fi channel, but in 2008. 
Here's a clip:




You can always show a YouTube preview by pasting the link directly instead of embedding it into a text.

IT wasnt gurren lagann. ive watched that before. the pilots were in the mech from the start, they didnt combine. and i saw it was when i was way younger and graduated in 2007 so thats why i say 2005 at very latest
